# why range(0,10).remove(1) does not work?

Tags: python, list

why

```
range(0,10).remove(1)
```

does not work?

I know the question is pretty short, but I do not have any idea why this thing does not work..
Is it possibe to write it in one line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`x = range(0, 10)` will return either a list or a `range` object (depending on your Python version).

#### Python 2.x

`x = range(0, 10).remove(1)` will return `None` as `list.remove` will modify the list *in-place* and so returns `None`. Your list is created and the value `1` removed, but as it is never assigned to anything, it's garbage collected.

#### Python 3.x

`x = range(0, 10).remove(1)` will return an `AttributeError` as [`range` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) don't have a `remove` method. If you convert it to a list using `list(range(0, 10)).remove(1)` you'll have the same issue as Python 2 though.

A way to get what you want would be to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). In the list comprehension you'll iterate over `range(0, 10)` but use an `if` statement to only add a value that isn't 1, such as:

```
x = [i for i in range(0, 10) if i != 1]
# [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Might be better to use `[i for i in xrange(0, 10) if i != 1]` with Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `remove()` method operates "in place", and doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `remove` is an in-place operation, and therefore returns `None`.

It does indeed do what you think it does: create a list from `0` to `9`, then removes the element `1`, but that is a temporary list that is not assigned to any variable.

As an alternative, a list comprehension could achieve this

```
>>> [i for i in range(0,10) if i != 1]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `remove` does not work is already covered.
I'd like to present an alternative to the `list comprehension` method:

```
In [1]: filter(lambda x:x!=1, range(10))
Out[1]: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

While the list comprehension is considered more pythonic, `filter` might sometimes be closer in expressing the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

The result is `None` because `list.remove()` doesn't return anything. You could workaround that by using a `lambda` function and the `or` operator.

In Python 2 this one-liner would work:

```
(lambda lst=range(0, 10): lst.remove(1) or lst)()
```

or this in Python 3:

```
(lambda lst=list(range(0, 10)): lst.remove(1) or lst)()
```

Both execute faster than using a list comprehension would (although it's not quite as readable):

```
> python -mtimeit "(lambda lst=range(0, 10): lst.remove(1) or lst)()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.467 usec per loop

> python -mtimeit "[i for i in range(0, 10) if i != 1]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.815 usec per loop

> c:\python3\python -mtimeit "(lambda lst=list(range(0, 10)): lst.remove(1) or lst)()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.817 usec per loop

> c:\python3\python -mtimeit "[i for i in range(0, 10) if i != 1]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.17 usec per loop
```

Comment: why is the or operator necessary?

Comment: @JFFIGK: It's needed so the result of the expression will be the (updated) `lst`. It works because of the way the Python `or` operator works.